# Why python print the last key

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration

I am new in python and wondering about the result. I just want to understand it.
suppose I have the following dictionary:

```
employee = {   
   'user_name': 'my name',   
   'password': 'hello',   
   'mobile phone': 123456789
}

for i in employee:    
    print(i)  

print(i)
```

and here is the result:

```
user_name
password
​mobile phone​
mobile phone
```

if you notice that the (**mobile phone**) has been printed twice.the *second* one comes from the second print in the above code.

1. Why this is happen?
   I expected to get this error:

> NameError: name 'i' is not defined

as usual by python.

2. what if I want to access the first or second key? can I access with the same what I access the last one (without writing the key name or number)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is the scope :

Python's scope behavior is defined by function scope : please see here for more [documentation](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)

Since you are running into the main function, the `i` var will still be defined in the `print` statement , because it is in the same scope of the `for` loop.

So it will have the value of the last iteration of your loop (i.e "mobile phone")

```
#global scope (main function)
 employee = {   
   'user_name': 'my name',   
   'password': 'hello',   
   'mobile phone': 123456789
}

for i in employee:   
    #you are still in the global scope here !!
    print(i)  

#and here too....so the "i" variable will have the value of your last iteration !
print(i)
```

To be more clear, if you would write something like :

```py
    #global scope (main function)
     employee = {   
       'user_name': 'my name',   
       'password': 'hello',   
       'mobile phone': 123456789
    }
    def show_employees() :
        for i in employee:   
            #you are in the "show_employees" function scope here !!
            print(i)  

    show_employees() # here you call the function

    #and here you will get your "expected error" because "i" is not defined in the global scope
    print(i)
```

Output :

> File "main.py", line 18, in 
> print(i)
> NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Scope in Python is a bit different than in other languages like C++, C# or Java. In those languages, declaring

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { ... }
```

`i` would only be defined in the scope of the loop. That's not the case for Python. `i` remains existent and has the last value it was assigned.

> what if I want to access the first or second key? can I access with the same what I access the last one (without writing the key name or number)?

No. Except you make the loop stop at a different position.

Comment: I don't think "the complete form" to iterate on a Python `dict` is `for key, value in dictionnary: ...`, try it and you will see `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. Using `for key in dictionnary` does what the OP expect, iterating on the key. And I guess you are thinking about iterating on `dictionnary.items()`.

Comment: @mgc is right ! `for key, value in employee.items()` is the correct syntax here

Comment: @mgc: true. That's just the form when used with `.items()`. My bad. I removed it